# Need tool to "strip" HTTP basic authentication

Tags: linux, http

The title sounds a bit nefarious, but it isn't really.

I have a few IP webcams in my house. They all have the ability to serve up moving images in the form of an multipart-jpeg stream. For example, if I go to `http://frontdoor-cam/videostream.cgi` I get a multipart-jpeg showing my front porch.

Right now all of these cameras use HTTP Basic authentication. There is no option to turn it off.

I would like to have a web page where I can look at all of these cameras without having to enter *n* userid/password combinations. I have tried embedding images using URLs like `http://userid:password@frontdoor-cam/videostream.cgi` but Chrome (and apparently other browsers) are apparently removing support for this style of URL for "security reasons". (I assume it has to do with phishing attacks.)

So what I'd like to do is have some software running on my Linux box that will act as a mediator. A request for `http://mylinuxbox/whatever/frontdoor.foo` would perform the request to `http://frontdoor-cam/videostream.cgi`, passing in the credentials (which I'd just include in its configuration) and stream back the response (streaming is important, as an unending stream of jpeg images are sent back).

I'm hoping something already exists that can do this fairly easily. The software could either be something standalone that runs on its own port, or it could be an Apache module. (I already have Apache 2.2 running on my machine.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is a reverse proxy running on your Linux box.  You can then have requests to the proxy access the cameras using the `http://username:password@domain/` syntax.  Most webserver software can be setup as a reverse proxy.

- Apache uses [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html)
- Nginx has the [HttpProxyModule](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html)
- lighttpd has [mod_proxy](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModProxy)

Comment: Ah, yes, "reverse proxy" was the term I was looking for! I also had no idea that `mod_proxy` could operate in that mode. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is an elaboration on heavyd's answer, more than anything else. Based on his answer, here's what I ended up doing in my Apache config:

```
LoadModule proxy_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule headers_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_headers.so
```

...

```
<Proxy *>
    Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPassMatch ^/cams/noauth/([-a-z]*)/(.*)$ http://$1-cam/$2

<LocationMatch "/cams/noauth/">
    RequestHeader set Authorization "Basic dXNlcmlkOnBhc3N3ZA=="
</LocationMatch>
```

This makes it so that any request to `http://mylinuxbox/cams/noauth/LOCATION/WHATEVER` will reverse proxy to `http://LOCATION-cam/WHATEVER`, and the appropriate Authorization header will be sent.

One caveat I discovered during this: browsers generally have a limit on how many concurrent requests they will send to a single host. With Chrome the limit happens to be 6. Firefox has a similar default limit, though it can be adjusted in about:config. Because the cameras all appear to be coming from a single host, and because they "stream" by keeping the connection open, only the first few cameras on a single page will display, and the remaining images will block waiting for the other cameras to finish (which never happens).

A possible workaround would be to use virtual hosts, subdomains, or perhaps even additional ports to make the single server appear to be multiple servers.